# Request.QueryString don´t receive values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, interop, query-string

Good morning everyone,

I have a system which needs send a e-mail with some variables that I have in my JS. The code, at begin, looks fine to me, but the Request.QueryString returns me nothing. I am trying to receive data from the URL with Request.Url.ToString() and that show me all the url sended by the JS, which means the JS is sending, but the Request.QueryString can´t read the values.

Can someone please help me with this? 
Below I show the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var nomeCarinha;

 $(document).on("click", "[id*=lnkView]", function () {
         $("#nome").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.sDisplayName").text());
         $("#Product").html($(this).closest("tr").find(".Produto").text());
         $("#IP").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.sNetworkAddress").text());
         $("#DC").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.dc").text());
         $("#comentario").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.sComment").text());
         $("#inicio").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.inicio").text());
         $("#mensagem").html($(this).closest("tr").find(".mensagem").text());
         $("#monitor").html($(this).closest("tr").find("td.sMonitorTypeName").text());
         $("#dialog").dialog({
             width: 1000,
             title: "Detalhes para TP",
             buttons: {

                 Email: function (nome) {
                     var width = 150;
                     var height = 250;
                     var left = 99;
                     var top = 99;
                     var nome = $(this).find("#nome").text();
                     var produto = $(this).find("#product").text();
                     var ip = $(this).find("#IP").text();
                     var dc = $(this).find("#DC").text();
                     var comentario = $(this).find("#comentario").text(); 
                     var inicio = $(this).find("#inicio").text();
                     var mensagem = $(this).find("#mensagem").text();
                     var monitor = $(this).find("#monitor").text();

                     var janeleira = window.open("outlookPrimeiro.aspx?nomeDevice="+nome+"&nomeIp"+ip+"&nomeDc="+dc+"&nomeComentario="+comentario+"&nomeInicio="+inicio+"&nomeMonitor="+monitor, 'janela', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no, setTimeout=1000');
                // Rescrever no outlookprimeiro.aspx para tirar os + no lugar de espaço da URL 
                     },

                 Ok: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }

             },
             modal: true
         });

         return false;
     });

     function blinker() {
         $('.blink').fadeOut(500);
         $('.blink').fadeIn(500);
     }

     setInterval(blinker, 1000); //Runs every second
```

And the receive:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//NECESSÁRIO PARA USAR MARSHALL
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//NECESSARIO PARA USAR O OUTLOOK
using aqueleLance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
using testeUsingPrimeiro = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AutoFormatRule;
using testeUsingSegundo = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AutoFormatRules;
using testeUsingTerceiro = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AutoFormatRule;
using testeUsingQuarto = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AutoFormatRules;


public partial class outlookPrimeiro : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String nomeDevice = Request.Url.ToString();
        //String nomeProduto = "TESTE";
        String nomeIp = Request.QueryString["ip"];
        String nomeDc = Request.QueryString["dc"];
        String nomeComentario = Request.QueryString["comentario"];
        String nomeInicio = Request.QueryString["inicio"];
        String nomeMonitor = Request.QueryString["monitor"];

    //DEFINICICOES DE DADOS DO E-MAIL A SER ENVIADO
        String paraEmail = "noc@email.com.br";
        String copiaEmail = "mateus@email.com.br";
        //String copiaOculta = "";
        String assuntoEmail = "Usando Outlook 2013
        String corpo = "<html><body><div style='width:95%;text-align: center;background-color: black'><table style='width: 100%;text-align: center'><tr style='background-color:#5B2E90'><td style='color: white'>Prioridade</td><td style='color: white'>Acionamento</td><td style='color: white'>KBN</td><td style='color: white'>Device</td><td style='color: white'>IP</td><td style='color: white'>DC</td><td style='color: white'>WUG</td><td style='color: white'>Diretorio</td><td style='color: white'>Monitor</td><td style='color: white'>Comentario</td><td style='color: white'>Tempo Down</td><td style='color: white'>Inicio</td><td style='color: white'>TP</td></tr><tr><td style='color: orange'>Prioridade</td><td style='color: orange'>Acionamento</td><td style='color: orange'>KBN</td><td style='color: orange'>" + nomeDevice + "</td><td style='color: orange'>" + nomeIp + "</td><td style='color: orange'>" + nomeDc + "</td><td style='color: orange'>WUG</td><td style='color: orange'>Diretorio</td><td style='color: orange'>" + nomeMonitor + "</td><td style='color: orange'>COMENTARIO</td><td style='color: orange'>Tempo Down</td><td style='color: orange'>" + nomeInicio + "</td><td style='color: orange'>TP</td></tr></table></div></body></html>";

        //CRIA NOVO APP USANDO Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
        OutlookApp appDoOutlook = new OutlookApp();

        //CRIA E-MAIL
        aqueleLance.MailItem itemDoMail = appDoOutlook.CreateItem(aqueleLance.OlItemType.olMailItem) as aqueleLance.MailItem;

        //QUAL CONTA VAI ENVIAR?  NECESSÁRIO TER A CONTA NA MÁQUINA
        string nomeDaConta = "noc@linx.com.br";

        //CRIA SESSÃO
        aqueleLance.NameSpace sessao = itemDoMail.Session;

        //PEGA CONTAS PRESENTES NA MÁQUINA
        aqueleLance.Accounts contaAccounts = sessao.Accounts;

        //FOR 1 ATÉ FINAL DO NÚMERO DE CONTAS
        for (int i = 1; i <= contaAccounts.Count; i++)
        {
            //aqueleLance.Account contaAccount RECEBE O VALOR DO FOR
            aqueleLance.Account contaAccount = contaAccounts[i];

            //SE A CONTA EXISTE, ELE VAI ENVIAR
            //(COMPARAÇÃO FEITA EM LOWER CASE
            if (contaAccount.DisplayName.ToLower() == nomeDaConta.ToLower())
            {
                //COMANDO PARA ENVIAR USANDO A CONTA XXXXX
                itemDoMail.SendUsingAccount = contaAccount;

                //LIBERA VARIAVEL
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contaAccount);

                //PARA O COMANDO
                break;
            }
        }
        //PARA QUEM ENVIA O E-MAIL
        itemDoMail.To = paraEmail;

        //ENVIAR COM COPIA PARA
        itemDoMail.CC = copiaEmail;

        //COPIA OCULTA
        //itemDoMail.BCC = copiaOculta;

        //ASSUNTO DO EMAIL
        itemDoMail.Subject = assuntoEmail;

        //CORPO DO EMAIL EM HTML
        itemDoMail.HTMLBody = corpo;
        //"<html><body>Enviado pelo <strong>Outlook</strong> 2013<br/> Teste do envio com CC e BCC.<br/><br/></body></html>"
        //IMPORTANCIA DO EMAIL
        itemDoMail.Importance = aqueleLance.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;

        //ENVIA O EMAIL
        //NÃO É POSSÍVEL VER ANTES DE ENVIAR SEM HABILITAR O DISPLAY ABAIXO
        //itemDoMail.Send();

        //HABILITE ISSO PARA VER A MENSAGEM ANTES DE ENVIAR
        //PRECISA TIRAR O SEND ACIMA
        itemDoMail.Display(false);            

        //LIBERA CONTAS
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contaAccounts);

        //LIBERA SESSÃO
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessao);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the same keys for your values:

```
"nomeDevice="+nome+"&nomeIp="+ip+"&nomeDc="+dc+"&nomeComentario="+comentario+"&nomeInicio="+inicio+"&nomeMonitor="+monitor
```

So you should also read these in the C# code:

```
    String nomeIp = Request.QueryString["nomeIp"];
    String nomeDc = Request.QueryString["nomeDc"];
    String nomeComentario = Request.QueryString["nomeComentario"];
    String nomeInicio = Request.QueryString["nomeInicio"];
    String nomeMonitor = Request.QueryString["nomeMonitor"];
```

Also note that you should absolutely escape the content on the JavaScript side using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), otherwise your users can make the request fail by having for instance a `&` in the comentario... e.g.:

```
"outlookPrimeiro.aspx"+
"?nomeDevice="+encodeURIComponent(nome)+
"&nomeIp="+encodeURIComponent(ip)+
"&nomeDc="+encodeURIComponent(dc)+
"&nomeComentario="+encodeURIComponent(comentario)+
"&nomeInicio="+encodeURIComponent(inicio)+
"&nomeMonitor="+encodeURIComponent(monitor)
```

Comment: WORK´S FINE HERE!
Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try To change:

```
String nomeIp = Request.QueryString["ip"];
```

To

```
String nomeIp = Request.QueryString["nomeIp"]
```

and so on...

also, there's small typo. **+"&nomeIp"+ip+** should be **+"&nomeIp="+ip+**

Comment: Nothing change, still can´t see any value.